# How to set hover for button on xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

How to set hover for `Button` on `Xamarin Forms`?

Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLfAW55_4cY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hover effects make sense for Desktop applications where you have a mouse but for Mobile applications ? It doesn't even make sense .

But if you want to show effects in Xamarin forms,it's pretty simple to do so using single lines.

like:

```
Button.TranslateTo(100,0,500,Easing.CubicIn);
Button.TranslateTo(0,0);
```

`Easing` provides many kind of animation effects for your situational needs.

Basically,there are 4 effects:

```
1.TranslationTo
2.ScaleTo
3.RoatationTo
4.FadeTo
```

Follow this 8 minute tutorial ,if you want more info: [Xamarin.Forms Animation Effects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypKnAKJL9CA)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by creating a custom renderer. I believe it's only usefull on an UWP build, so not for android and IOS. Here's a [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63089/button-on-hover-text-colour) where you can find more information.